# React Native Maps Error - Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I’m struggling with the Google Maps API in React Native, for **Android**.

I’ve followed the [installation instructions](http://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) for Android but I keep receiving the same error (see title) when I try to use the `Mapview` Component. I'm using the Android Studio emulator.

[image: Red screen I'm receiving]

versions: *react native* - **0.55.4** / *react-native-maps* - **0.18.0** and **0.22.0**

Haven't found any online solution for Android. Does anyone has a way to get me out of this trouble?

Please, tell me if you want to see my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really struggled with this for a few days also. I think it's a bug with the installation process, and it's very frustrating their docs no longer provide manual installation instructions. Honestly, I eventually gave up and used react-native-mapbox-gl

Comment: Really frustrating, man! I was also thinking about using react-native-mapbox-gl and now your comment incentivates me even more, since I have super short dates to finish this app.

Comment: I was told that it's free until you use it 50000 times. How was your experience? Did it met your needs? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Absolutely, nothing against react-native-maps, I've used react-native-maps before and it's worked great (previous version). If they had manual installation instructions for the current version I'd probably still be using it.

From my understanding and what I've seen so far (don't quote me on any of this), Mapbox allows up to 50,000 users, and then charges progressively. Cool thing is it looks like they're actually checking monthly active users to derive your total. Doing the math i think it's like $200/mo at 300K users, which isn't bad. I think being paid brings better support.

Comment: Thank you so much again! Taking what you said, I think it's time for me to try react-native-mapbox too.